Why the cropped photo with ExtImageView package from github has a very low resolution
Does anyone know why the resolution of cropped images with this package has a low resolution?
https://github.com/wwdablu/ExtImageView
I don't know what to try to make it work. Maybe is a setting somewhere I don't know about. The author didn't say nothing on the gitub page about that.
I found here under BitmapStorage.java  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos); and I modified to
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

but no effect. What do you think?
